# Get all of location data of that city

Tags: facebook

I want to get location data of my city. I don't know what I should to use, FQL or API.

Now, I do follow the developer's guide on FB. I can login and show info from myself only.

Comment: absolutely, in developer documentation is show all

Comment: facebook not provide location data from any city..you can just have loged users location access and and its friend location access using extended permission..

Comment: Only get my and my friend info? and If I want to know location of place on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can user the Search API as described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/#types

To get the information about places, see this example:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000

Comment: Thanks for link but I can't test your sample :(